# Tagger entries orderby

Tags: devdemon-tagger

I'm using Tagger from devdemon and I wonder if it is possible to ordeby a customfield. It seems to me that the entries are orderby entry_date and I can't find a way to change it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, there isn't one. However, looking at the add-on code, it appears you can either order by entry_title, entry_date, or random.

However, it would be quite easy for you to go into the logic and add another case statement to the existing switch/case statement. Look for this line:

```
switch ($this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('orderby'))
```

in this file:

```
/system/expressionengine/third_party/tagger/mod.tagger.php
```

Then just add another case statement or modify the add-on to take any value:

```
    switch ($this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('orderby'))
    {
        case 'entry_title':
            $this->EE->db->order_by('ct.title', $sort);
            break;
        case 'random':
            $this->EE->db->order_by('RAND()', FALSE);
            break;
        default:
            $this->EE->db->order_by('ct.entry_date', $sort);
            break;
    }
```

For instance, you could modify the default statement to accept any value; just know it will error if you provide a bad value (since this directly modifies the MySQL statement):

```
        default:
            $orderby = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('orderby');
            $this->EE->db->order_by($orderby, $sort);
            break;
```